# UITabBarController switching tabs guidelines

Tags: ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, switching, design-guidelines

Is it correct according to guidelines to switch tabs using 'not tabs' but some other controls like buttons?

Comment: I did this and they accepted my app. Not sure about the guidelines though.

Comment: did my answer clear out your doubts